# Esconder formularios en Laravel 5.5 solo de forma visual

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-5

Me encuentro haciendo un proyecto en Laravel 5.5. Tengo el siguiente formulario para editar un post:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que los únicos formularios que pueda ver el usuario son el de notas y el de descripción. El resto de los otros campos tendran ya un valor en la base de datos de manera que el usuario como no los puede ver, no pueda modificarlos. He leído que hay una forma de hacerlo con css, ya que solo quiero esconderlo de forma visual.

Aquí coloco el codigo del formulario:

```
{{ Form::hidden('user_id', auth()->user()->id) }}

<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('category_id', 'Categorias') }}
{{ Form::select('category_id', $categories, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('name', 'Nombre de la etiqueta') }}
{{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('slug', 'URL amigable') }}
{{ Form::text('slug', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'slug']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('file', 'Imagen') }}
{{ Form::file('file') }}
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('file2', 'Notas') }}
{{ Form::file('file2') }}   
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('status', 'Estado') }}
<label >
    {{ Form::radio('status', 'PUBLISHED') }} Publicado
</label>
<label >
    {{ Form::radio('status', 'DRAFT') }} Borrador
</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('tags', 'Etiquetas') }}
<div>
    @foreach($tags as $tag)
    <label>
        {{ Form::checkbox('tags[]', $tag->id) }} {{ $tag->name }}
    </label>
    @endforeach
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('excerpt', 'Extracto') }}
{{ Form::textarea('excerpt', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '2']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('body', 'Descripcion') }}
{{ Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">{{ Form::submit('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary']) }}</div>

@section('scripts')
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/stringToSlug/jquery.stringToSlug.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/stringToSlug/jquery.stringToSlug.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#name, #slug").stringToSlug({
        callback: function(text){
            $('#slug').val(text);
        }
    });
});

CKEDITOR.config.height = 400;
CKEDITOR.config.width  = 'auto';

CKEDITOR.replace('body');
</script>
@endsection
```

**EDIT1:**  Los usuarios estan resgistrados en la aplicación.

Cuando un administrador crea o edita un post puede usar todos los campos.
Solo hay un administrador, lo diferencio ya que este tiene un valor en su id de 1, el resto usuarios con valores de id distintos de 1 son simples usuarios.

Cuando un usuario crea un post puede usar todos los campos. Cuando un usuario edita un post solo puede editar el campo de notas y el de descripción, de manera que los otros campos conserven los valores que se les coloco cuando se creo el post.

Comment: Los usuarios de los que hablas ¿Vendrían siendo usuarios registrados en tu aplicación? Si esto es así, me gustaría saber si en tu aplicación diferencias entre usuarios y un usuario 'administrador', ya que supongo que el objetivo de ocultar los campos y no eliminarlos es porque en algún momento alguien tiene que visualizarlos (Por ejemplo, un administrador).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primera forma:**

La forma más sencilla de hacer esto con CSS es incluir la siguiente linea en cada uno de las partes de tu formulario que **no** desees que se muestren a los usuarios:

```
<div class="form-group {{ Auth::user()->id != 1 ? 'hidden' : '' }} ">
    // Code
</div>
```

Siendo `hidden` la etiqueta de CSS siguiente:

```
<style>
    .hidden { display: none; }
</style>
```

**Segunda forma:**

Otra forma de hacerlo sin necesidad de utilizar CSS sería utilizar en cada parte que **no** desees que vean tus usuarios y sólo sea accesible para el administrador la etiqueta de laravel blade `@if`, de la siguiente manera:

```
@if(Auth::user()->id == 1)
    <div class="form-group">
        // Code
    </div>
@endif
```

**Tercera forma:**

Sería la que yo usaría, de forma que no haya que añadir tanto código. Supongo que en tu vista principal tienes un `@yield('styles')`, que permite añadir estilos específicos en cada uno de tus vistas. De esta forma, en la vista que nos ocupa añadiriamos:

```
@section('styles')
    @if(Auth::user()->id != 1)
        <style>
            .hidden { display: none; }
        </style>
    @endif
@endsection

// ...

<div class="form-group hidden">
    // Code
</div>

// ...
```

Esta forma mezcla las dos anteriores, pero utilizando menos código. Tendríamos que añadir la etiqueta `hidden` a los campos que no quieres que vean los usuarios. De esta manera si alguien que no sea el administrador carga la vista, se activa la etiqueta `hidden` y se ocultan.